# Pandas string search partial string

Tags: python, pandas

I've the following data

`list = ['good dog','bad cat']`

`pattern = '|'.join(list)`

```
|column|
|---|
|bad cat|
|good dog|
|cat|
|dog|
```

When I do the string contains in pandas, only the fully matched string gets True output as below

`df[column].str.contains(pattern,regex=True)`

```
|column|
|---|
|True|
|True|
|False|
|False|
```

Would it be possible to do something like fuzzy match where partial strings within a pattern are also checked for? So that output would all be true since "Cat" and "Dog" are partially present?

Thanks.

Comment: split the pattern list and join by `|`?

Comment: pattern = "|".join(["%("+x.replace(" ", "|")+")%" for x in list]) could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Custom Metric

Write a crude fuzzy match metric.  You can probably adjust this metric by removing high frequency words and stemming appropriately.

```
def fuzz(a, b):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    b = np.asarray(b)
    c = a[:, None] == b[None, :]
    return min(c.max(0).mean(), c.max(1).mean())
```

This calculates how many words from one list matches how many words from another.

We build a dataframe to help illustrate.

```
d = pd.DataFrame([
    [fuzz(a, b) for b in map(str.split, lst)]
                for a in df.column.str.split()
], df.index, lst)

d

   good dog  bad cat
0       0.0      1.0
1       1.0      0.0
2       0.0      0.5
3       0.5      0.0
```

We can see that we get a metric of `1.0` for the first row and `'bad cat'` and the second row and `'good dog'`.  For the third and fourth rows, we get measures of `0.5` meaning half the words matched.

Now you set a threshold and find if any in a row exceed the threshold:

For a threshold of `.5`

```
df[d.ge(.5).any(1)]

     column
0   bad cat
1  good dog
2       cat
3       dog
```

For a threshold of `.6`

```
df[d.ge(.6).any(1)]

     column
0   bad cat
1  good dog
```

---

#### Levenshtein

Use Levenshtein's distance ratio

```
import Levenshtein

c = pd.DataFrame([
    [Levenshtein.ratio(a, b) for b in lst]
    for a in df.column
], df.index, lst)

c

   good dog   bad cat
0  0.266667  1.000000
1  1.000000  0.266667
2  0.000000  0.600000
3  0.545455  0.200000
```

And you can do the same threshold analysis as above.